# "XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only" error message

Tags: xml-rpc

When I load my site without www I get the error message: 
"XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only." but when I use www. then it loads fine... I have googled it, checked youtube for hours but can't find a solution to this particular problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you spoken to your host?

Comment: Also, when you say you're loading your site, which URL are you using? And how are you using it?

Comment: Yes, the host told me to install a plugin that is called "Disable XML-RPC" that didn't help at all. Then they told me that they can't help me.

Comment: Everything works fine when I'm using https://www but when I use https:// then it does not load, instead I get an error that says: XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only.

Comment: Can you be more specific though, e.g. are you loading the homepage? Is this in a browser or something else? Are you trying to load XMLRPC? I know it might seem too obvious to mention from your point of view, but for all I know you're trying to load `/wp-json` on a playstation. Can you use `example.com` so that it's clearer what you mean? e.g. do you mean `https://www.example.com` when you say you use `https://`? Or do you mean `https://example.com`? It isn't clear

Comment: Thanks for getting back so fast.... Yes I am loading the homepage in a browser, chrome, forefox, safari I(same outcome no matter what browser I use) https//www-example-com and it loads without issues but when loading https//example-com then I get the error. I have tried to disable xmlrpc with a plugin but that didn't help. Contacted the host but they were not able to help either. ( I do not have Jetpack plugin installed either which might cause this particular problem )

Comment: Tried to disable plugins, but no luck..... I have no idea what else to do. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Jetpack is not the cause, it sounds like your server is loading 2 different sites, not the same site, but it's impossible to tell with just the information available. Your host is the best option for you, and there's an extremely high chance that only your host can diagnose and fix this. This is not normal WordPress behaviour. As an aside, put `die("this is my site");` at the top of `xmlrpc.php` in order to prove that `www.` and `non-www` are not the same site. If they are the same site then something is misconfigured.  Keep in mind it could be your own files ( .htaccess? )

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thanks a lot. I have however talked to my host for hours now and I can totally forget that they will help my fix this. This is an issue I can't deal with myself because I have already tried literally everything that I'm capable of and no luck. ( by far the worst wordpress issue during all the years I have used wordpress so far) Do you by any chance know what to do in this situation and where to turn for help?

Comment: By the way, inner pages work fine and redirect as they are supposed to from  https//example-com/innerpage.php to https//www-example-com/innerpage.php

It is only the homepage that gets the error message: "XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only."

Comment: No, the direction users are appointed to when this occurs is always to contact the host. Triple check your HTAccess/Nginx rules to make sure they're correct, otherwise I'm sorry, the reported symptoms are too vague to identify a cause on their own. Also keep in mind this isn't a discussion forum, it's a QA site, you need to be able to ask a specific question and be able to mark an answer as correct, not just for your situation but for all. It looks like the diagnosis stage of this is unfinished

Comment: I understand. I have checked my .htaccess and replaced it with the original one as well and that did not fix the issue. I have been talking to my host since yesterday on chat but they have not done anything beside making suggestions that I have already tried myself like disable plugins, revert backup and so on. (the usual things) I have also changed PHP version but that didn't do anything.

Comment: After troubleshooting for hours and hours I have finally found what is causing this and it is caching plugin called Swift Performance. Disabling it didn't help before but after removing it manually and removing every line of code it left behind in several wordpress files resolved the issue and the site redirects fine.

This is very weird however because I have:

1. Exact same setup (same theme, same plugins) on a different website with a different host and everything works fine with Swift Performance

Comment: 2. I have installed Swrift Performance on a different domain on the host I'm having issues with just to test if the host somehow blocks the plugin or something but it doesn't seem to be the case
since it works on the test domain and with the same plugin settings.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: If disabling and cleaning up swift performance resolved the issue then I think you need to raise this with swift performance support